# How to configure tomcat to redirect ip address

Tags: tomcat, redirect

We are using `Tomcat 8.5`. The site is hosted at `https://foo.bar.com`.

The site can be accessed by entering the `IP` address in the address bar `https://111.111.111.111` ( of course the browser warn the user about certificate problem)

Is it possible to configure the `Tomcat` so that entering the IP redirects user to host. in this way entering the `https://111.111.111.111` will redirect to `https://foo.bar.com`.

Comment: Reverse DNS is the solution. But for that you need to make changes at DNS server.

Comment: You can also try using /etc/nsswitch.conf on your computer for IP to host resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be very simple to write a [Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html) for this.

The tomcat 8 also ships with a [rewrite valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html), which sounds like something you are looking for.

But why should you do this? Normally nobody would like to use an IP address if you provide a Name via DNS.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do this if you find a certificate authority that provides a certificate for an IP address. However, despite never having tried this, I doubt that one exists - I'd rather expect them to explicitly be forbidden to do so, as IP addresses change and, quite frankly, nobody navigates to a website by IP address unless you're in a development system.

Development (or "in house") use is the key to your workaround here: If you're only working internally, not public facing, you can create (and self-sign) a certificate for both the DNS name and the IP, and accept it once.

If it's a (large) intranet, you might have an internal CA, where they may do this (but I doubt).

Naturally, this only works for internal purposes, nothing public-facing. But you wouldn't hand out your system's IP address to any customer anyway, right? That's exactly what DNS is for. Plus it allows clients to connect through IPV6.